# Android/data folder on KitKat

Tags: android, directory, android-4.4-kitkat

I was just wondering, how can I create Android/data folder for my application, for example,   Android/data/Myapp in removable external sd card, because I was reading, that google now doesn't allow apps to write files on external sd card, except for app specific folders.

Comment: please be more specific to your problem

Comment: I want to save some files on external sd card in my app specific folder, but at first I need to create them. How can i Do that?

Comment: Did you google [how to create folder in external sdcard](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2131051/2591002) ???

Comment: Yes, but i need to know how to do that on KitKat, because it's not allowing me to create a folder.

Comment: please try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26055638/2591002)

Comment: File dir = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);

this line made both directories on internal an external sd card, thanks!

Comment: glad it worked for you.. :)