# Is this below code is correct for saving logcat details to a file in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

```
public static void saveLogcatToFile(Context context)
{    
    String fileName = "logcat_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".txt";

    File outputFile = new File(context.getExternalCacheDir(),fileName);

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")

    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f "+outputFile.getAbsolutePath());  
}
```

Please check the above code and help me **to save the logcat details to file (permanently), it should append after everytime debugging in eclpise**.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
public static void saveLogcatToFile(Context context)
    {
    try {
                Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

                StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    log.append(line);
                }

                String logFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "LogTest.txt";

                File logFile = new File(logFilePath);
                if (!logFile.exists())
                    logFile.createNewFile();

                FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(logFile, true);
                byte[] buffer = log.toString().getBytes();

                outStream.write(buffer);
                outStream.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();

            }
    }
```

And don't forget to mention the permissions in Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

At last also check this [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26055638/2811956) For writing file on external storage.