# Can´t write in SD card in some devices

Tags: android

In all devices in sd card path. For example "/storage/extSdCard" path. This path is selected by user (me) in file explorer, not constant.

I use

> java.io.File.canWrite() : **The java.io.File.canWrite() method verifies whether the application can write to the file denoted by this abstract path name.**

Function and I get true in all times. In some devices in new file create in this path, the file is created ok. But in other devices the file is not created, and I not get exception, warning, block or something. Simply the file is not created.

I tested with 2 Android 4.4 devices. One can write and other can´t write.

Why I can not write in these cases?

Comment: Which Android version do these devices use ? Google changed the permissions needed for writing to SD: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23514506/android-kitkat-4-4-folder-on-sd-card

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android KitKat 4.4 folder on sd card](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23514506/android-kitkat-4-4-folder-on-sd-card)

Comment: I tested with 2 Android 4.4 devices. One can write and other can´t write.

Comment: OK, so we can exclude this. Add this information to your question for others to read. There are plenty more questions about similar problem here on SO with different approaches while opening the SD. Tried them already ?