# Android kitkat 4.4 capturing images from camera not saving images to sd card but save it to internal storage of phone

Tags: android, android-camera, android-4.4-kitkat, android-sdcard, android-image

i have been tried  since last two days to save images to sd card while capturing from camera app but it always save images to phone internal storage or also not create any folder or images i.e save this things to sd card. it always store to phone internal memory. i am testing on KitKat 4.4 version android device.so it is particular platform issues or something else that google has taken back to support sd card to store images.what is the exact issues. i dont know.please help me to resolve this issue. i have googled SO answer lots but not getting any proper answer.Thanks in advance. what i have done so far.its as following.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final int requestCode = 20;
    int imagenamecounter = 1;
    private ImageView imageHolder;
    private String imageFilePath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageHolder = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        Button capturedImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        capturedImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent photoCaptureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                startActivityForResult(photoCaptureIntent, requestCode);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (this.requestCode == requestCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            String partFilename = currentDateFormat();
            String storeFilename = "photo_" + partFilename + ".jpg";
            storeCameraPhotoInSDCard(bitmap, storeFilename);

           imageHolder.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }


        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmm").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        String mImageName = "MI_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + mImageName);
        return mediaFile;
    }


    private String currentDateFormat() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HH_mm_ss");
        String currentTimeStamp = dateFormat.format(new Date());
        return currentTimeStamp;
    }

    private void storeCameraPhotoInSDCard(Bitmap bitmap, String currentDate) {
        // File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  File.separator+"Viral images"+"photo_" + currentDate + ".jpg");
        try {
            String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"viralDir";
            //  + File.separator + "ViralF";
            File file = new File(extr, "images " + currentDate);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream);
            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();
            //  MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(),
            //      bitmap, file.getPath(), "images " + imagenamecounter);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        imagenamecounter++;
    }


}
```

Comment: There is no way to get external sd card path programmatically. Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() will always return the path of your primary storage which may be internal sd card most of the times.

Comment: I have also tried another way still no luck to store images to sdcard like /sdcard/"profile. jpg" like but still problem to save images

Comment: you can not assign hardcoded path for external storage like /sdcard it differs from device to device check this link for more information https://gist.github.com/PauloLuan/4bcecc086095bce28e22

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check. But I have heard that Google has taken back support for sdcard card to store images for Android kitkat 4.4. Is it right????

Comment: still not working. refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23514506/android-kitkat-4-4-folder-on-sd-card .  Google has blocked write access to external storage devices in Android 4.4. Until they change it there is no way to revert it back without root.